# Why I'm getting a response without asking the question?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, comments, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Look at this [Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504049/how-can-we-reduce-kxml-size-by-gzip-compression-for-j2me). The user's name is **bharat**. He asked the question. My name is **bharath**. I edited his question when he asked.

I didn't add any comments or answers on his question. If any users add the comments on his question, I'm [getting the response.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488433/bharath?tab=responses)  Look on [my responses from other users.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488433/bharath?tab=responses&sort=all&StartDate=2011-12-14%2005:25:11Z&page=1).

That question comments directly comes to my responses. Is this bug? I have been using Stack Overflow since the past year, but didn't face this type of issue before.

Comment: Short answer: your name is a subset of the person being responded to. Since comment replies allow responding to the author of the post, other comments, or editors by typing @ followed by at least three characters of their name, this means you *both* get the response. For more details, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work

Comment: @ Shogging, Thanks for you quick reply and you clear my doubt. :)